# Python requires_grad_ is not supported on ScriptModule

Tags: python, text, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I tried running code from this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-built-an-ai-text-to-art-generator-a0c0f6d6f59f but I get this error when running the code:

```
RuntimeError: requires_grad_ is not supported on ScriptModule
```

This is the colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sf9I2Wg8c_mwwDwM3mGsIW3zLWOmA7xG?usp=sharing

On the internet I found that for some people it worked by installing pytorch==0.10.0, i tried this but it did not fix the issue. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is pytorch 0.10.0 a typo? Pytorch stable is 1.10.0.

Comment: As an aside, please post the minimal code to reproduce the error here (not a link to a colab).